# forms.ValidationError bug?

Tags: django, django-forms

this is my third day in django and I'm working on my validation form and i came across this weird bug where my validation form didn't do anything so here's the code

```
class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):

email = forms.EmailField(label="E-Mail", error_messages={'required': 'Please enter your name'})

class Meta:
    model = LowUser
    fields =['fullname', 'email', 'password', 'bio']
    widgets = {
        'password' : forms.PasswordInput()
        
    }

def clean_fullname(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data.get("fullname")

    if 'ab' in data:
         raise forms.ValidationError('invalid')
    else:
        return data
```

if i input "ac" to the fullname it works perfectly fine it adds the input to the database. But if i input "ab" it didn't do anything it doesn't give me any errors nor add the input to my database. And I'm pretty sure my `forms.ValidationError` is bugging because if i change my `raise forms.ValidationError('invalid')` to `raise NameError('Test')` like this

```
def clean_fullname(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data.get("fullname")

    if 'ab' in data:
         raise NameError('Test')

    else:
        return data
```

and i input "ab". It works completely fine and it gave me this page

[image]

and I'm using django 2.1.5 if you're wondering i would appreciate any help

thank you in advance

Comment: It will not raise any errors. It will specify that `form.is_valid()` is `False`, and the error will be in `form.errors` in your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If i input `"ac"` to the fullname it works perfectly fine it adds the input to the database. But if i input "ab" it didn't do anything it doesn't give me any errors nor add the input to my database.

That is **expected behavior**, `ValidationError`s are used to collect all errors.

The idea is that you raise `ValidationError`s. These are all collected, and when one such error is present, `form.is_valid()` will return `False`, and the `form.errors` will contain a dictionary-like object with all the errors. The reason this is done is to collect problems with *all* fields in one single pass, such that it does not only report the first error of the form data.

Imagine that you have five fields with mistakes, and the form only reports problems with the first field. Then it takes five rounds before all fields are validated. By collecting all errors, it can show multiple ones. You can even return multiple errors on the same field.

For more information, see the [*raising ValidationError`* section of the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/#raising-validationerror).

Comment: I've solved it thank you so much man. and also a little question if you don't mind. If this `form.is_valid()` returns false will it re-render my form to add a little error message on top of my input? if yes then i already have a clear idea of this.

Comment: @Ihopemyenglishisgood: normally yes. If you pass *that* `form` (so not create a new one) again to the template, and render the form in the template it will show errors. If you want to manually render the form, you can also render the errors. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Willem i realized that the problem was in my views.py.

```
def registerForm(request):


  regisform = RegisterForm()
  cntxt = {'mainregisform': regisform, 'tst': ''} 
  if request.method == 'POST':
      regisform = RegisterForm(request.POST)

      if regisform.is_valid():
          regisform.save()



   return render(request, 'userregister.html', cntxt)
```

i thought that the `ValidationError` wasn't giving me any errors because usually there's an error message on top of my input box, but it actually did gave me an error. the problem was i define the `mainregisform` before the `regisform` got re-rendered therefore i never got error message